# Capturing small audio samples from microphone in Java

Tags: java, send, microphone, javasound

I want to capture small audio samples (actually to send it through internet real-time). The samples should be small, the smaller the better. I've read some articles about audio routines but saving audio takes some time and I need it really fast. Maybe there is easier way to stream the input and send it real time?

Comment: It seems you this needs a streaming solution.  What is the actual feature you are trying to achieve?  By 'small' do you mean 'short in duration' or 'low number of bytes'?

Comment: @Andrew Thompson  I mean both. Im coding voice-chat. The quality doesn't have to be the best :)